# how to check and replace the null date using xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to check if my expiry date is null than i want to take the value from CreationDate.

My XML is like

```
 <CreationDate>2017-03-18</CreationDate>         <ExpiresDate>20170318</ExpiresDate>
```

and in my xsl

```
<xsl:element name="NewDeliveryDueDate">
<xsl:call-template name="FormatDate">
<xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="Product/ExpiresDate"/> 
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:element>
&comma;
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You should post a *complete* example of the input XML, including a "null" expiry date. I also cannot see what your XSLT has to do with the stated problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is incomplete. Perhaps this could work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ExpiresDate[not(string())]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(../CreationDate, '-', '')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to the following example input:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <CreationDate>2017-03-18</CreationDate>
        <ExpiresDate>20170318</ExpiresDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <CreationDate>2017-03-09</CreationDate>
        <ExpiresDate/>
    </item>
</root>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <item>
      <CreationDate>2017-03-18</CreationDate>
      <ExpiresDate>20170318</ExpiresDate>
   </item>
   <item>
      <CreationDate>2017-03-09</CreationDate>
      <ExpiresDate>20170309</ExpiresDate>
   </item>
</root>
```